# SAML issuer field does not get my custom value

Tags: java, spring-boot, saml, spring-saml

I am new to SAML but what I want to do is to change the Issuer in the authrequest of the SAML request.
What I did is to go to the documentation of SpringBoot and follow the instructions and I found the following : Create a yaml file and insert the following in order to change the issuer :

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        aaaaa:
          identityprovider:
            entity-id: "my issuer value"
            singlesignon.sign-request: false
```

The thing is that this does not work and everywhere else on the internet I did not find anything similar that could help me.

Does anyone know how to dynamically change the issuer from a yam file ?

Kind regards to everyone kind to help or suggest me something.